# open play store when app not installed in android by clicking the link from browser or mail App

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am working with deep linking feature in my app. My requirement is,

When my app not installed in a device during user clicks my specified link
(eg. http://www.showonthecloud.com ) from device browser or gmail app , want to redirect my app's google play store page. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where is the mentioned link? Is that in html page?

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement that link on your web server so that it lets them know they can download the app (assuming that you are using a link that you can manage on the web)